# Posting XML using HttpClient in .NET Core

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, coreclr

In Full .Net HttpClient has [extension](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclientextensions_methods) method to [post as XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclientextensions.postasxmlasync#M:System.Net.Http.HttpClientExtensions.PostAsXmlAsync%60%601(System.Net.Http.HttpClient,System.String,%60%600)), Is there equivalent package available in .NET Core to serialize the object as xml and post?

Comment: No. Most likely because .NET Core doesn't have built-in serializers. However, there's nothing stopping you from writing an extension yourself.

Comment: what serializer we should be using `System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer' or `System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer'